# Legality of minifying plugins javascript

Tags: javascript, minify

I am using several plugins for a site.  What is the legallity of minifiying all of these plugins into one file?

Is this is allowed or do I have to keep them seperate?  I understand there are multiple licenses but just as a general practice, is this considered ok?

Comment: Here's a good related discussion: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/45033/can-i-minify-javascript-that-requires-copyright-notice

Answer (score 2):

It depends of the plugins you are using. You need to carefully read the "license" or "legal" section of the site of every script you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Well, simplicity says to keep them separate, and just load each one on the pages.  This has the added benefit of allowing you to only load the ones needed on a given page.  Also keeps things neater, I find a lot of small files is much more manageable then one large file.

If you really want to merge them, give each one an obvious start and end, give all credit where credit is due, and read the individual plugin's licenses (making sure it doesn't have something about this case).

Comment: Hi @mazzzzz - thats kind of what I have been doing, basically just psting all of the plugins including their header comments into 1 big js file.  It has reduced my http request from around 7 to 1 although I now have 1 big file.  I suppose its a balance

Comment: Yes, it would equal about the same traffic.

Comment: It offers better performance to minify all your scripts in one single file. The merged file wille be smaller, and by doing so you diminish the number of HTTP requests required to display a web page. Using the "304 not modified" header finishes the optimization, as the file is downloaded only once per user. The display time of my pages has greatly decreased since I do this, and so has my server load.

Comment: Good to know, I never found much of an improvement doing it.  I will look at this next time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine anything bad ever happening with any license as long as you include the license and possibly a link to the original, e.g.:

```
/* MIT License for some plugin
   Author: Bob */
function(){ minified code... }

/* Another plugin's license */
function(){ minified code... }
```

Also, even if the license prohibits modification to the code, I would strongly argue that minifying is not modification (as long as you link to non-minified code).

Comment: The problem is that minification code usually strips out comments.

Comment: Most minification scripts have an option to not strip the leading comment.  Some also have an option to not strip specifically formatted comments.